# How to: mock module dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Tearing my hair out on this one.

I have the following module/controller I wish to test

```
angular
    .module('monitor.tableLord.controller', ['monitor.wunderTable'])
    .controller('TableLordController', TableLordController);

    TableLordController.$inject = ['$scope', 'historyState'];
    function TableLordController($scope, historyState) {
        ....some code....
    }
```

The module monitor.wunderTable contains a directive that should be loaded before the controller, but the controller I want to test does not actually depend on monitor.wunderTable. monitor.wunderTable does however have a LOT of other dependencies....

My testfile:

```
describe('TableLordController', function() {
    var $scope, historyState;

    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.module('monitor.wunderTable', []);
        module('monitor.tableLord.controller');
    });

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller('TableLordController', {$scope: $scope, historyState: {}});
    }));

    it('loads', function() {
        $scope.$digest();
    });
});
```

For some reason (I didn't think this should be possible), my mock version of monitor.wunderTable is interfering with the tests i have for this module. Every test of the controller defined in this module now fails with: "Argument 'WunderTableController' is not a function, got undefined".

I case it is relevant, here is my the definition of monitor.wunderTable:

```
angular
    .module('monitor.wunderTable', [
        'ui.grid',
        'ui.grid.infiniteScroll',
        'ui.grid.autoResize',
        'monitor.wunderTable.service'
     ])
    .controller('WunderTableController', WunderTableController)
    .directive('wunderTable', wunderTable);

function wunderTable(){...}
WunderTableController.$inject = [];
function WunderTableController(...){...}
```

Edit: Posts suggesting that I remove the module dependency (as it is not strictly needed) will not be accepted as correct answer (and possibly downwoted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion comes from misunderstanding how modules work in Angular. Modules [are stored inside `angular`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/loader.js#L28). Once they are overriden, they are overriden for the current test run, not for the current spec. Module mocking isn't supported by ngMock (it would require some substantial changes in Angular core) and `beforeEach` won't help anything.

Unless you want to run test suites in separate runs, the solution is to backup the module before mocking it. In some cases `angular.extend` and `angular.copy` are unable to handle complex objects properly. `Object.assign`, `jQuery.extend` or `node-extend` may be better candidates. In the case of `extend`s deep copy can also used if necessary.

So in one test suite it is

```
var moduleBackup = angular.module('monitor.wunderTable');
angular.module('monitor.wunderTable', []);

describe('TableLordController', function() {
    ...
```

And in another

```
Object.assign(angular.module('monitor.wunderTable'), moduleBackup);

describe('WunderTableController', function() {
    ...
```

The good thing about TDD is that it clearly indicates the flaws in app design and teaches the developer to write test-friendly code in immediate and ruthless manner. Module dependency implies that the components inside the module depend on the components from another one. If they doesn't or they are coupled too tightly, this can be considered a potential flaw and the subject for refactoring.

The fact that the solution is hack-ish and tends to break makes it unfit for testing.

TL;DR: Yes, you have to remove the module dependency.

Comment: "Your confusion comes from misunderstanding how modules work in Angular. Modules are stored inside angular. Once they are overriden, they are overriden for the current test run, not for the current spec. Module mocking isn't supported by ngMock (it would require some substantial changes in Angular core) and beforeEach won't help anything."

Comment: "...Once they are overriden, they are overriden for the current test run, not for the current spec. Module mocking isn't supported by ngMock"

Whaaaaaat! Didn't expect this. It also contradicts the only useful tutorial (read: tutorial that told me what I wanted to read) I found http://www.sitepoint.com/mocking-dependencies-angularjs-tests/#mocking-modules

I'm not entirely sure where to put the module dependency as it contains a directive that is used by the html of controller under discussion.

Somewhat bitter that I cant mock modules. It makes testing a bit clunky. Thx for your clarification

Comment: You won't find much information on the subject exactly because it isn't very practicable in angular. Yes, the article may do a bad turn. It introduces a speculative example which mocks the modules for *all* specs, something that doesn't take place in real-world app. You may even meet the workflows where the modularity was driven to extremity, each controller and directive is defined on its own module with no dependencies, and they are loaded by parent module. It may look messy and impractical, but now you know what it was for: testability.

Comment: Since you stick to namespaced module name convention, it may suggest the module hierarchy: 'monitor.tableLord' and 'monitor.wunderTable' are isolated modules and they are both loaded in parent 'monitor'.

Comment: Thx. I will do that. Your comments have brought much clarity:)