# angular karma unit test using $httpBackend + $resource without bootstrapping with module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, jasmine, karma-runner

## Requirements

- Angular based REST client component
- Must interact between a private API and services
- Karma/Jasmine test does not bootstrap app module

## Current dilemma

We do not want to bootstrap the entire application for unit tests (using module() or angular.mock.module()). It does not seem sustainable for an enterprise level application, even though Angular's component registration is a useful feature. All the examples I have found do it this way, however per our current business objectives, I need to do it without bootstrapping the app module.

So far I have successfully injected both $resource and $httpBackend and they are functional. I can assign a respond behavior to the $httpBackend object, and I can inject $resource into the restClient factory in the test suite. However when I try to run it, it appears that they are not aware of each other, and therefore the client is actually sending calls (undesirable #1), leaving the $httpBackend object waiting with outstanding expectations and nothing to flush (#2).

## Please help

Can you point out the configuration errors I'm missing to get these two pieces to work together with out calling module()?

## Testing errors

```
Error: No pending request to flush !
        at Function.$httpBackend.flush (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1544:34)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/folders/8h/lqyqq1ks6vv8z5mpsxjqn5sw0000gn/T/89bece8e9480f44013f53b3f1b05b4ba.browserify:855:22 <- src/app/services/restClient_test.js:24:0)
Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET https://ourlink.nl
        at Function.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1577:13)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/folders/8h/lqyqq1ks6vv8z5mpsxjqn5sw0000gn/T/89bece8e9480f44013f53b3f1b05b4ba.browserify:847:22 <-
```

## Browser error from failed restClient XHR

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load undefinedhttps://oursite.nl?userId=UserZ. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

## restClient.js:

```
function restClient ($resource, baseUrl) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        get: get
    };

    function get (route, options) {
        var self = this;
        var payload = $resource(self.baseUrl + route, options).get(options.routeParams);
        return payload;
    }
}

module.exports = restClient;
```

## restClient_test.js:

```
describe('restClient', function () {
    var client, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));

    beforeEach(function () {
        var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngResource']);
        this.client = require('./restClient.js');
        client = this.client($injector.get('$resource'));
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('sends a get request', function () {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('https://oursite.nl')
            .respond('200', {userId: 'UserZ'}, {token: '1234'});
        client.get('https://oursite.nl', {userId: 'UserZ'});
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you suppose it to work? You keep using 'inject' but don't want to use 'module'. And thus your $injector differs from the one which is used by ngMock. ngMock is a part of the framework (quite useful and thought-out part), and you should love it or leave it, as with any framework.

Comment: We *are* using ngMock, which is where we get access to inject. I should not need the entire app for a unit test. Ultimately this was not my decision to not bootstrap the app with module(), but I think he (our architect) has a point. In any case, those are the requirements. If you don't like it, you don't have to help.

Comment: You have my sympathies then, this kind of decision and the need to recreate ngMock functionality won't make testing easier. It looks like XY problem to me, which may result from the lack of modularity (similar to [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33655195/3731501)). When modules are designed with tests in mind, there's no need to bootstrap the entire app.

Comment: I'm not sure that we are recreating functionality. We just want a little less functionality. A unit of code should be testable as a single unit. That's all we're after. Now that we got it working, it is actually quite nice.

Comment: you may often stumble upon excessive 'one component, one module' modularization, e.g. 'foo.bar.bazController'. It may be a bit verbose in production code because JS lacks namespace features, but decoupled unit tests are exactly what it is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using ngMock Jasmine/Mocha helpers it has to be something like this:

```
describe('restClient', function () {
    var $injector, client, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function () {
        $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngResource', 'ngMock']);
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        this.client = require('./restClient.js');
        client = this.client($injector.get('$resource'));
    });
    ...
});
```

Comment: You really saved the day with this help. I was so close! Than you, @estus